# how do i get job id of batch prediction job on vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, branch-prediction

i need to get the prediction details of batch prediction job which are stored on google cloud storage, however to get that i need to get JOB ID from BatchPredictionJob

i tired to write the results to a json file as shown below but its failing

```
with open('batch_prediction_job.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(batch_prediction_job, f)
```

A similar question is answered once we have the JOB Name however getting job name seems to the tricky bit

full function

```
batch_prediction_job = model.batch_predict(
    instances_format='jsonl',
    job_display_name=f"batch_predict",
    gcs_source=['gs://demo/batch/items.jsonl'],
    gcs_destination_prefix='gs://demo/batch/',
    machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    starting_replica_count=4,
    #sync=False
)
```

Comment: You can go through this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-create-batch-prediction-job-sample) or you can follow this [Git Link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/aiplatform/src/main/java/aiplatform/GetBatchPredictionJobSample.java) for get job id of batch prediction may be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

job_id = batch_prediction_job.name.split('/')[-1]